# Deflect Arrows used on thrown area effect weapons

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats

When [deflect arrows](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/deflect-arrows-combat) is used it says you take no damage from it.  If a thrown AOE weapon (Such as a flask of acid or an Alchemist bomb) is thrown at a target with deflect arrows, what happens to the thrown weapon?  Does it vanish and do nothing?  Does it scatter and still perform AOE damage and ignore the deflecting target?  Does it do something else?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As Pathfinder has a basis largely in simulation, I rule in this case (I have a monk PC in my game and it's come up) that he can deflect the full effect of the weapon but still takes any splash damage.

Comment: Same in mine.  This isn't that unusual of an edge case, especially in Alchemy heavy games.

Answer (score 4):

For my game I rule that the player is allowed to deflect an AOE weapon.  They get to role a reflex save against the attack role that was used to hit them.  If they succeed they can choose which direction they deflected the attack to; if they fail it gets randomly deflected (d8 roll for direction).

I then have the attack hit the square that it was deflected too, and then figure out splash damage from there.  If there's a creature in the deflected square I use the original attack roll to see if it hits that creature.

This can lead to some interesting strategies.  One game saw our monk deflecting a flaming oil onto a summoned fire elemental in order to heal it from the fire damage.

Answer (score 1):

By RAW, a character hit with a [splash weapon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Throw-Splash-Weapon) also receives the splash damage.

> [...] A hit deals direct hit damage to the target, and splash damage to all creatures within 5 feet of the target. [...]

The target is, in fact, a creature within 5 ft. of itself.

However, a character using the [Deflect Arrows](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/deflect-arrows-combat) feat, explicitly receives no damage from the ranged attack. The feat does not force the attack to miss: it simply negates the damage. In fact, the splash weapon doesn't *misfire* and it still deal splash damage to adjacent creatures.

---

That said, what @mxyzplk wrote:

> Pathfinder has a basis largely in simulation

stands true, and I'd take no offense nor scandal from house ruling that a deflected alchemist's fire still deals splash damage to its target.

Comment: -1 for now. That's not how it works. The creature hit only takes direct hit damage. "When you hit a target with a splash weapon, the contents sprays out over the target and everything within 5 feet of that target. The target struck takes damage for a direct hit; other targets take splash damage. The splash weapon's direct and splash damage ratings are given in the weapon's description." http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/rg/20070717a

Comment: And yes, that's a post about 3.5, but the rule is the same for Pathfinder.

Comment: @Cthos, Skip Williams is adding personal interpretation to the RAW. The word "_other_" in "other targets take splash damage" is in addition to what the Player's Handbook states... even if this interpretation is probably RAI.

Comment: But you're also interpreting that something is within 5ft of itself (and by correlation included in creatures), which I do not believe is possible, as written. And given that Skip Williams was one of the contributors to the PHB, I'd say that is in fact not how it works.

Comment: I really fell within 5 ft. from myself :)

Comment: Lol. *sigh*. Can you also occupy a space within 5 feet of the space you are currently in simultaneously? I mean, without Dimensional Agility that is.

Comment: As the rules are written, there is no need to be simultaneously in a square and in another square 5 ft. apart. In euclidean space every point is within any distance from itself (a spot is even within 0 ft. from itself) and for simple mathematical reasons. This is not a personal interpretation. You have the point in saying that Skip Williams (being a freelancer contributor to Wizards) had the right of explaining the rules and correct the wording so that they better accommodate the original intention. But applying them as written on the PHB simply converge to the target taking splash damage too.

Comment: Okay, even if we accept your logic, that means that FAQ answers produced by authors are pointless, and until errata comes out we should blindly follow RAW even when RAI is clearly spelled out. That's ridiculous. Sorry, -1 stands.

Comment: No problem for the -1. I was not trying to convince you in removing it and this is exactly the mechanic SE encourages. Neither I'm saying that FAQ are pointless: both the second half of my answer and my penultimate sentence in my last comment encourage RAI. I think I appeared polemic because of I insisted on the 5 ft. self-proximity issue :) Sorry about that, I apologize.

Comment: No worries, that is as you say the way things go. :)